# Python 2.7, dpkt, and pyvisa

Tags: python, python-2.7, visa

when I simply use this single line of code:

```
import dpkt
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import dpkt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import ethernet
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\ethernet.py", line 128, in <module>
    __load_types()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\ethernet.py", line 122, in __load_types
    mod = __import__(modname, g)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\ip6.py", line 101, in <module>
    import ip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\ip.py", line 258, in <module>
    __load_protos()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dpkt\ip.py", line 255, in __load_protos
    IP.set_proto(v, getattr(mod, name.upper()))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VISA'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please post the relevant code (at least, the `import` line)

Comment: this error is called when I simply type in: "import dpkt"

Comment: What version of dpkt? What environment are you running in? Im using latest dpkt on python 2.7.5 and it imports fine.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5 and the newest dpkt

Answer (score 0):

The dpkt issue page has a patch for this problem. The second patch at https://code.google.com/p/dpkt/issues/detail?id=34 fixes the import issue.